# What's the iteration order of NSSet?

Tags: objective-c, ios, iteration, nsset

I know that NSSet does not preserve order and I got curious about how the iteration order is implemented in iOS4/iOS5 sdks. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The order is undefined, as explicitly stated in the [`allObjects` method description](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/allObjects). It probably depends on the underlying implementation and could change at any time.

Comment: Yep I know that it could change any time and you should not do anything depending on it. Although it's not told explicitly, it sure has an algorithm and that's what I was curious about.

Comment: Ditto.  Most likely they start at one end of the hash array and work through.  But even if you know the hash values, the size of the hash array can vary, based on history, and that will affect the ordering of a given hash value.  About all you can say is that if two elements are close to each other in one case they have a higher than "average" chance of being close to each other in another case.  (Which is to say that you shouldn't depend on iteration order to "randomize" a set of elements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
The order is random.

**Long Answer:**
By definition, the order is not specified. In other words, it depends on the implementation.
In common implementations, every object is converted to an integer number (hash code) which is used to find the object in the set quickly (indexing hash table) and the iteration order is then implemented by hash codes (a hash code is basically an array index).

Note that if two objects have the same hash code (but they are not equal), their order depends only on the sequence of insert/delete operations on the set.

Since common hash table implementations use different hash functions for different data sizes, the order can change completely when set size is increased.

Comment: If someone is interested in the implementation of NSSet, CFSetRef is open source and can be found at opensource.apple.com. Its likely that this implementation is the same through all the classes in the class cluster since they are interchangeable.